# Retrieve all data under node in firebase realtime database

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase realtime database and want to use the data to make a leaderboard. Im trying to retrieve all the data in my Scores node but am not sure how to loop through to get the scores of all users.

The database structure is as below: 
[image]

The code I have tried to use is this:

```
package com.example.securityapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import static java.lang.System.in;

public class leaderboard extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseReference databaseUsers;
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    TextView score;
    private static final String TAG = "leaderboard";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_leaderboard);

        databaseUsers = database.getReference().child("Scores");
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.leaderboard_score);


        databaseUsers.child("Scores").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        System.out.println("The scores are " + dataSnapshot.child("Points").getValue().toString());
                    }
                }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
             // Getting Post failed, log a message
             Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());

    }


});

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going one level too deep into your JSON and are reading `/Points/Points`. Since that node doesn't exist, you get an empty snapshot in your `onDataChange`.

```
database.getReference().child("Scores").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "The scores are " + dataSnapshot.child("Points").getValue(Long.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
});
```

**New Code that returns values:**

```js
public class leaderboard extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseReference databaseUsers;
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    TextView score;
    private static final String TAG = "leaderboard";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_leaderboard);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tableText);


        database.getReference().child("Scores").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        System.out.println("The score is: " + snapshot.toString());
                        score.setText(snapshot.toString());
                    }
                }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
             // Getting Post failed, log a message
             Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());

    }


});

        }
}
```

This is my progress:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though you are using a "Listener" class to access the data and print out the scores. The "ValueEventListener" listener you attached, with the "onDataChange()" method implemented, would not be called until there is a data change.

I'm not sure how you are using this class, but based on your question, I am assuming that you just want to print the scores when the "leaderboard.onCreate()" method is executed. Is this correct? If that is the case, you may not need to be attaching a listener.

Comment: Thanks for the response! That’s exactly it. I need to display the high scores on the leaderboard screen when the user clicks “Leaderboard” from the menu. I would like the values to be retrieved from firebase and displayed in a table on the leaderboard screen

Comment: Ok, cool. Have you tried that code without it being inside a Listener?

Comment: "the `onDataChange()` method ... would not be called until there is a data change." This is not true.  From [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events): "You can use the `onDataChange()` method to read a static snapshot of the contents at a given path, as they existed at the time of the event. **This method is triggered once when the listener is attached** and again every time the data, including children, changes." (emphasis mine)

Comment: @schwissig How should the code look without the valueListener?

Comment: I am able to return the scores now, but was wondering is there anyway to only return the points, without the ID key? Please see Edit for my progress